# I've a docker images which fail on amazon linux only

Tags: docker, dockerfile, amazon-linux

I've created a docker images on my local machine which works just fine, but when I upload to my remote machine (a Amazon Linux) each time I try to run it it return `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` I can't figure out where is the problem, can someone help me? This is my dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Golang runtime as a parent image
FROM golang:1.8-alpine

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# Run weatherai when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/weatherai"]
```

Comment: Have you copied contents of the folder in which dockerfile is present?

Comment: Yes I follow the guide on the official docker site

Comment: First of all you should build the image inside the container and not copy it form your host OS. See if this helps https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/docker-golang/. Make sure to do a cross OS build

Comment: I try to follow the guide but it didn't change the final result :/

Comment: I handle it! Thanks for your second link I find where was the problem, I've to update the docker file in order to permit SSL managment! Thanks!